# Typescript merging 2 arrays and increase qty if they have the same id

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm doing with my Angular 8 project and I want to merge 2 arrays into 1 and increase qty if they have the same value in the object. I have tried a few times by myself and it does not really work well.

```
mergedOrderList: any[]= [];

lstOldOrder: any[] = [
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},];

lstNewOrder: any[] = [
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},
{id: "", products_id: "", qty: 1, ...},];

lstNewOrder.forEach(newOrder => {

    let isDubplicated: boolean = false;

    lstOldOrder.forEach(oldOrder => {

      if (newOrder.products_id == oldOrder.products_id) {
        oldOrder.qty += newOrder.qty;
        isDubplicated = true;
        mergedOrderList.push(oldOrder);
      }
    });

    if (!isDubplicated) {
      mergedOrderList.push(newOrder)
    }

  });
```

I did like this and they work when they both have the same products_id. But when new order doesn't have products_id. They skip my old order and add only new order to the list. I'm not quite sure I'm done it right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the problem is that you are only adding data from `lstOldOrder` in `mergedOrderList` if the
`product_id` of new list item matches with any item in old list.

So you are not able to see any item from old list if all the items are new in `lstNewOrder`

Instead what you should do is :

Add the item to the `mergedOrderList` but increase the quantity if there is a match.

```
mergedOrderList = [];

lstOldOrder = [
  { id: "1", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
  { id: "2", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
  { id: "3", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
];

lstNewOrder = [
  { id: "4", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
  { id: "5", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
  { id: "1", products_id: "", qty: 1 },
];

lstNewOrder.forEach((newOrder) => {
  Oindex = -1;
  lstOldOrder.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id == newOrder.id) {
      Oindex = index; // Getting the Index of that item in old array.
    }
  });

  if (Oindex != -1) { // if that item was in old Array
    newOrder.qty += lstOldOrder[Oindex].qty; // Increase Quantity in newOrderItem
    lstOldOrder.splice(Oindex, 1); // Delete that Item from OldArray
  }
  mergedOrderList.push(newOrder); // Add the Item in Merged
});

mergedOrderList.concat(lstOldOrder); // Finally add all the remaining Items
```

All the edge cases in the code are not handled properly sorry for that.
Feel free to edit my answer, it may help someone else